# Android - Is it possible to switch camera during a video call programmatically

Tags: android, video, android-activity, call, android-camera

I managed to open a video call using the following code:

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent("com.android.phone.videocall");
    callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);     
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "0528322206"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Now, I would like to switch camera to the back camera programmatically (by default the screen  use the front camera but i want to use the back camera).
Is it possible?
Can I replace the entire screen with my own activity so I can control the layout etc.?